# is magento sales eav

Tags: magento, entity-attribute-value

By checking sales module's config, there is sales_entity section as below

```
<models>
<sales>
    <class>Mage_Sales_Model</class>
    <resourceModel>sales_resource</resourceModel>
</sales>
<sales_entity>
    <class>Mage_Sales_Model_Entity</class>
    <entities>
        <quote>
```

and those class `Mage_Sales_Model_Entity_xxx` extends `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract`, showing that sales/order is `EAV` style but not flat one.
I can also find table "eav_entity_type" have a lot of records related with "order".

But, I go through the code, sadly, `EAV` is not at last in place in current codebase (at least v1.7).
Can anyone help to clarify? Is `EAV` for sales/order deperecated?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the latest versions of Magento (i.e. 1.6 and 1.7, can't say for earlier) the sales entity attributes are no longer stored in the EAV attribute-value tables. The resource models of the Mage_Sales module connect the sales entities to flat tables.

You can also see that the base Sales model class `Mage_Sales_Model_Abstract` extends `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract`, and the base Sales resource model `Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Abstract` extends `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract` - neither of those is an EAV model or an EAV resource model.

The attribute-entity metadata that you find in the table `eav_entity_type` is similar to the EAV entities of the Catalog and Customer modules, yet the attribute value storage system is not EAV.

I guess, the configuration you encountered is left for the backward compatibility.

I've put together a description of the Magento's EAV system, you may find it interesting: http://www.divisionlab.com/solvingmagento/magento-eav-system/

Comment: so, order, invoice, creditmemo, shipment are not EAV structured?

Answer (score 2):

I've compared old Magento versions and found a big difference on Sales Order Model between 2 versions 1.4.0.1 and 1.4.1.0

This file was added to create the sales_flat_order and remove Order EAV tables
Mage/Sales/sql/mysql4-upgrade-1.3.99-1.4.0.0.php - Line 1144

```
// Remove previous tables
$tablesToDrop = array(
    'sales_order_entity_decimal',
    'sales_order_entity_datetime',
    'sales_order_entity_int',
    'sales_order_entity_text',
    'sales_order_entity_varchar',
    'sales_order_entity',
    'sales_order_decimal',
    'sales_order_datetime',
    'sales_order_int',
    'sales_order_text',
    'sales_order_varchar',
    'sales_order'
);

foreach ($tablesToDrop as $table) {
    $table = $installer->getTable($table);
    if (!$installer->tableExists($table)) {
        continue;
    }
    $installer->getConnection()->query(
        'DROP TABLE ' . $installer->getConnection()->quoteIdentifier($table)
    );
}
```

The resource class file Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Order was changed to extends from Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Order_Abstract instead of Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract

Magento also noted about the changes from EAV to flat sales on this version might be a very heavy operation.

I believe we can't use EAV for the orders as same as products or customers anymore.

Comment: so we know the exact point we switch from eav to flat, which could be helpful for those who want to get eav back. at the other hand, even for product table, we have flat table besides eav via reindex process. hopefully, magento community could present more performance statistics for those versions.